# What is the meaning of this conversation before making love?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-piano

In *The Piano* (1993), Ada and Baine have a conversation like this:

> Baine: How many would that be?
>
> Baine: Yes. Ten keys.

And then both make love with each other.

What is the meaning of this conversation before making love?

Comment: First of all, I'm pretty sure Baines says those lines. Ada is a mute. Second of all, don't they deal in piano keys the whole time? Way before this scene?

Comment: ["Then, at one time George comes out of his bedroom completely naked, everything present, as he tells dumbfounded Ada that she must lie naked with him for the piano. (They deal in keys; this event took ten keys)"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107822/reviews-110)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ada buys back the piano one key at a time by playing for him. Making love to him counts for ten times playing for him. At this point the relation between Ada and Baine is highly asymmetric: Baine desires Ada, Ada desires her piano. Only later does Ada fall in love with Baine.